# How to convert some of the db-sync data types/columns to C# data types?

Tags: cardano-db-sync, c#

Specifically, I am using the Npgsql lib in a C# console app, and am reading data just fine so far for the obvious types like bigint, uinteger, boolean, etc. - but for a few different types/columns in some tables I am unsure:

- hash32type
- lovelace
- word64type

Can anyone point me to a resource that would provide me the required knowledge for converting these types into C# types?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL domain types like `lovelace` etc are created in the stage one migration scripts (`schema/migration-1*` of the repo). Eg `lovelace` is:

```
CREATE DOMAIN lovelace AS numeric (20, 0) CHECK (VALUE >= 0 AND VALUE <= 18446744073709551615);
```

From these domain types you should be able to figure out the appropriate language type for your language.

Comment: yes! In the repo - of course it is, thank you!

https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/acf795fdcb23be0038ffa19554f3c8b0c8c43ed9/schema/migration-1-0001-20190730.sql#L19